# How we can monitor a service status using Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

We are using Zabbix for server monitoring and its working fine for system resources like disk, CPU, memory etc.

Now we want to monitor some services also whether they are running fine or not like Apache, Nginx, Puma, Sidekiq etc.

Can you please help me how we can monitor such services using Zabbix?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to the documentation, it covers [windows service monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/windows_services) and [generic process monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent) with `proc.*` items.

[Here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/items/supported_by_platform) you can find the supported item by platform matrix.

There's an external template for systemd lld, you can find it on [Zabbix Share](https://share.zabbix.com/operating-systems/systemd-service-monitoring)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Earlier i have checked it and Apache, Nginx etc services are not mentioned in that list. what we need to select for apache service like http or service in key when we create item i.e `net.tcp.service[http,,80]`? Will it show down or Zero (0) in problem when service will stopped or killed?

Comment: The `net.tcp.service` is a simple check run by the Zabbix Server, it tries to connect to the specified port of the target in agentless mode. To check for apache service with the agent, use something like `proc.num[apache2,www-data]` as stated in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If we use `proc.num[,,,apache2]` what we need to select in application during item creation e.g zabbix agent, performance etc, many options are there. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Zabbix is quite a complex and powerful system, I suggest you to start from the provided quickstart guide: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

for Nginx monitoring you can use that [template](https://github.com/igogorevi4/Zabbix-Extensions/tree/master/Templates/Nginx)

also take a look this [repository](https://github.com/igogorevi4/Zabbix-Extensions), probably you can find there something useful

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please let me know how we add these template in zabbix server?

Comment: You should clone this repo to your laptop, then upload template (Templates/Nginx/nginx.template.xml) to Zabbix with Configuration -> Templates (button below). Then add Templates/Nginx/nginx.conf to you server that you want to monitor, and also add Templates/Nginx/nginx-status.conf to nginx configuration directory. Don't forget to reload nginx and zabbix-agent

Answer (score 0):

For sidekiq specifically, using

```
proc.num[,,,sidekiq]
```

seems to work. It uses the cmdline -argument.

Source:
https://zabbix-users.narkive.com/EKVrN9VY/proc-num-item-for-sidekiq-process